# Parsing xml files with scala

Tags: xml, scala, parsing, apache-spark

I am trying to process a xml file using scala and spark.

I have this schema:

```
root
 |-- IdKey: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CDate: date (nullable = true)
```

And I want to process this xml file:

```
<Item>
    <CDate>2018-05-08T00:00::00</CDate>
    <ListItemData>
        <ItemData>
            <IdKey>2</IdKeyData>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </ItemData>
        <ItemData>
            <IdKey>61</IdKeyData>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </ItemData>
    <ListItemData>
</Item>
```

I am using this code:

`sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Item")
  .schema(schema)
  .load(xmlFile)`

But my result is a table without the CDate column:

```
+------------+
IdKey         |Value    | CDate |
+------------+
|61           |1        | null
|2            |2        | null
```

Is possible parse the xml file with this schema ? I want to obtain this values:

```
+------------+
IdKey         |Value    | CDate |
+------------+
|61           |1        | 2018-05-08T00:00::00
|2            |2        | 2018-05-08T00:00::00
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your xml data a valid xml? I don't think it is a valid xml data

Comment: I forgot to close a tag. But the xml original is correct.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see your xml as an invalid 
The valid xml should look like this in your case

```
<Item>
    <CDate>2018-05-08T00:00::00</CDate>
    <ListItemData>
    <ItemData>
        <IdKey>2</IdKey>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </ItemData>
    <ItemData>
        <IdKey>61</IdKey>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </ItemData>
    </ListItemData>
</Item>
```

If you have this corrected `xml` data then you can create a `schema` as

```
val innerSchema = StructType(
  StructField("ItemData",
    ArrayType(
      StructType(
        StructField("IdKey",LongType,true)::
          StructField("Value",LongType,true)::Nil
      )
    ),true)::Nil
)
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("CDate",StringType,true)::
  StructField("ListItemData", innerSchema, true):: Nil
)
```

Apply this `schema` to read `xml` file

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Item")
  .schema(schema)
  .load(xmlFile)
  //Selecy nested field and explode to get the flattern result
  .withColumn("ItemData", explode($"ListItemData.ItemData"))
  .select("CDate", "ItemData.*") // select required column
```

Now you can get the required output

```
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|CDate               |IdKey|Value|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|2018-05-08T00:00::00|2    |1    |
|2018-05-08T00:00::00|61   |2    |
+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

You can let the spark to infer schema itself will get the same result

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "Item")
  //.schema(schema)
  .load(xmlFile)
  .withColumn("ItemData", explode($"ListItemData.ItemData"))
  .select("CDate", "ItemData.*")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Shankar I am testing this solution. It seems correct.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to configure more than one rowTag? For cases with different xml tags.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done, you can see the option here. https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#features

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do something like this this will output //( 2018-05-08T00:00::00   2 1   61 2   ,2018-05-08T00:00::00)
then you can format as you want i think, it will help.

  object XMLDemo extends App {
  val xmlElem: Elem = <Item>
  <CDate>2018-05-08T00:00::00</CDate>
  <ListItemData>
  <ItemData>
  <IdKeyData>2</IdKeyData>
  <Value>1</Value>
  </ItemData>
  <ItemData>
  <IdKeyData>61</IdKeyData>
  <Value>2</Value>
  </ItemData>
  </ListItemData>
  </Item>

  val lb: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
  val date: NodeSeq = xmlElem \\ "CDate"

  val r: immutable.Seq[String] = xmlElem.map {
    x => x.text
  }

  println(r.mkString(" ").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("\n"," "), date.text)
  }
```